How to load a *.mil into coremltools?
In Apple's documentation, Model Intermediate Language (MIL) is described as an intermediate language. I found many .mil files in Apple's system. You can easily find them using the following command:
find /System/Library -name "*.mil"

I am trying to study these .mil files and convert them into Core ML files to run them.
The example of apple shows us how to produce a mil program. However I cannot find anyway to load mil program from a *.mil file.
Here is the example of Apple.
# import builder
from coremltools.converters.mil import Builder as mb

# Input to MIL program is a list of tensors. Here we have one input with
# shape (1, 100, 100, 3) and implicit dtype == fp32
@mb.program(input_specs=[mb.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 100, 100, 3)),])
def prog(x):
    # MIL operation takes named inputs (instead of positional inputs).
    # Here `name` argument is optional.
    x = mb.relu(x=x, name='relu')
    x = mb.transpose(x=x, perm=[0, 3, 1, 2], name='transpose')
    x = mb.reduce_mean(x=x, axes=[2, 3], keep_dims=False, name='reduce')
    x = mb.log(x=x, name='log')
    return x
  
print(prog)

main(%x: (1, 100, 100, 3, fp32)(Tensor)) {
  block0() {
    %relu: (1, 100, 100, 3, fp32)(Tensor) = relu(x=%x, name="relu")
    %transpose_perm_0: (4,i32)*(Tensor) = const(val=[0, 3, 1, 2], name="transpose_perm_0")
    %transpose: (1, 3, 100, 100, fp32)(Tensor) = transpose(x=%relu, perm=%transpose_perm_0, name="transpose")
    %reduce_axes_0: (2,i32)*(Tensor) = const(val=[2, 3], name="reduce_axes_0")
    %reduce_keep_dims_0: (bool)*(Scalar) = const(val=False, name="reduce_keep_dims_0")
    %reduce: (1, 3, fp32)(Tensor) = reduce_mean(x=%transpose, axes=%reduce_axes_0, keep_dims=%reduce_keep_dims_0, name="reduce")
    %log_epsilon_0: (fp32)*(Scalar) = const(val=1e-45, name="log_epsilon_0")
    %log: (1, 3, fp32)(Tensor) = log(x=%reduce, epsilon=%log_epsilon_0, name="log")
  } -> (%log)
}

And here is the *.mil file from macOS
/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_UAF_Siri_Understanding/purpose_auto/86aa08fa2cf25cbea1f9f8dee8c0bdad3a3802b9.asset/AssetData/sr/Hermes/int8_conformer_matrix_split.mlmodelc/model.bnns.mil
program(1.0)
[buildInfo = dict<tensor<string, []>, tensor<string, []>>({{"coremlc-component-MIL", "5.33.5"}, {"coremlc-version", "1877.0.10.0.2"}, {"coremltools-component-torch", "2.0.1"}, {"coremltools-source-dialect", "TorchScript"}, {"coremltools-version", "7.1.2"}})]
{
    func main<ios17>(tensor<fp16, [256, 14]> conformer_cnn_cache_0_shared_in, tensor<fp16, [256, 14]> conformer_cnn_cache_1_shared_in, tensor<fp16, [256, 14]> conformer_cnn_cache_2_shared_in, tensor<fp16, [100, 256]> elayers_output_cache_0_shared_in, tensor<fp16, [100, 256]> elayers_output_cache_1_shared_in, tensor<fp16, [100, 256]> elayers_output_cache_2_shared_in, tensor<fp32, [101, 80]> feat, tensor<fp16, [1]> offset_in, tensor<fp16, [500, 768]> outputs_shared_in, tensor<fp16, [100, 256]> subsampling_cache_shared_in) {
            tensor<int32, [2]> var_52_begin_0 = const()[name = tensor<string, []>("op_52_begin_0"), val = tensor<int32, [2]>([-1, 0])];
            tensor<int32, [2]> var_52_end_0 = const()[name = tensor<string, []>("op_52_end_0"), val = tensor<int32, [2]>([101, 80])];
            tensor<bool, [2]> var_52_end_mask_0 = const()[name = tensor<string, []>("op_52_end_mask_0"), val = tensor<bool, [2]>([true

...

So my final questions are

Is there anyway to load a .mil file to a coremltools.converters.mil.mil.program.Program?

Is the mil in the Apple website above the same thing as in the /System/Library?


